# Category Missing from Backend and Frontend Menu but in search category showing it's products also showing

Tags: magento2, search, category-products

Any Help Category Not showing on Backend and Frontend Menu but in search category showing it's products also showing magento 2[image]

Comment: can you add a screenshot of it showing in the search?

Comment: Please try once by running php bin/magento indexer:reindex and php bin/magento cache:flush commands.